# Trying to split 3 different datastets from 1 column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split

I currently have a CSV column that contains three different datasets (P,T,C) looking like: P=  +0.456T=+12.659C=39.285

This is just one out of many records but all the data is separated the same with P,T,C. I have posted the dataframe head below:

[dataframe Head](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L3g0y.png)

I want to separate each individual component (P,T,C) and create a time series analysis.

Currently, I am using str.split() command but it does not seem to work.

My code is as follows:

```
df[['Pressure','Temperature','Conducivity']] = df['CTD_Data'].str.split('=', expand=True)
```

Dataframe name: df

Column name: df['CTD_Data']

Do I need to create a seperate dataframe for the aforementioned column?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Edit: I managed to solve this, the code is very janky so please let me know if there is a more efficient way but here it is:

```
  #Spliting CTD Data
df['CTD_Data'].str.split('=', expand=True)

#Naming Split columns, ignore column for generated P column 
df[['ignore','Pressure','Temperature','Conductivity']] = df['CTD_Data'].str.split('P|T|C', expand=True)

# Making Split columns as Strings
CTD_Pressure= df['Pressure'].astype(str)
CTD_Temperature= df['Temperature'].astype(str)
CTD_Conductivity= df['Conductivity'].astype(str)
```

Comment: post the dataframe head(at least, if not full df)

Comment: Sorry, I have include a link to the data frame head

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
s='P= +0.456T=+12.659C=39.285'
p = re.findall('[PTC]=\+?[0-9.]+',s.replace(' ', ''))
p
>['P=+0.456', 'T=+12.659', 'C=39.285']


[float(r.split('=')[1]) for r in p]
>[0.456, 12.659, 39.285]
```